# How to get all records by using 2 independent condition

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, join

I have a list of firstname and lastname. I want a generic query which searches a big master table for each individual using first name and last name and produce an ID value for each. In a nut shell I want records for which there was an ID value present.

```
AGARWAL  NEERU
AHMAD    ANEES
AHUJA    KARUMA
AHUJA    SAM
AL-HATTAB    EYAD
ALATRASH     FIDA
```

So I basically want to retrieve some result for these input as below.

```
1221    AGARWAL  NEERU
2323    AHMAD    ANEES
4432    AHUJA    KARUMA
1542    AHUJA    SAM
8777    ALATRASH     FIDA
```

The only approach I can think of is using in with where clause on fisrtname and lastname individually. Its not giving what I want because

```
select b.id,a.firstname, a.lastname from master_table a , ID_table b
where a.firstname in ('NEERU', 'ANEES', 'KARUMA', 'SAM', 'FIDA', 'EYAD')
and a.lastname in ('AGARWAL','AHMAD','AHUJA','ALATRASH')
```

Now the above query will also give me output for people like below: (You notice people with different first or last name combination than what I want)
3433    AHMAD   SAM

Comment: You tagged this `mysql` and `oracle`, which one is it?

Comment: You also have a Cartesian join between `master_table` and `id_table`, I assume you actually want some sort of condition to join these two together.

Comment: basic SQL knowledge: OR vs. AND

Answer (score 0):

You need to test each firstname/lastname combination separately, and combine them with `OR`. You also need a joining condition between `master_table` and `ID_table`

```
SELECT b.id,a.firstname, a.lastname 
FROM master_table a
JOIN ID_table b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE (a.firstname = 'NEERU' AND a.lastname = 'AGARWAL')
    OR (a.firstname = 'ANEES' AND a.lastname = 'AHMAD')
    OR (a.firstname = 'KARUMA' AND a.lastname = 'AHUJA')
    OR (a.firstname = 'SAM' AND a.lastname = 'AHUJA')
    OR (a.firstname = 'FIDA' AND a.lastname = 'ALATRASH')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use 'UNION' condition. 
You can have 2 queries with multiple conditions and merge the results using 'UNION'
eg:
 
    SELECT a,b,c FROM table WHERE a IS NULL 
    UNION
    SELECT a,b,c FROM table WHERE b IS NULL

Comment: yes thanks, i figured out. So there are 2000 sql selects which are unioned together. But do you have any suggestion to come up with a stored procedure to solve this thing.